# Need steps to deploy an Angular app on AWS Lambda instead of EC2

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

https://medium.com/swlh/serverless-angular-universal-with-aws-lambda-99162975eed0

This blog shows how to use `angular universal` framework to deploy angular app on Lambda.

---

But this framework performs 2 steps automatically -

```
1) creates a Lambda using CLoufromation and 

2) also deploys the Angular app on AWS Lambda provisioned in step #1.
```

---

But in my organisation CloudFormation is not an approved tool. Terraform is what we're supposed to be using.

---

So is there a way I can prevent `angular universal` from performing step #1 so that I can provision the Lambda using Terraform myself?

```
- And how do I deploy my angular app on lambda myself?
```

---

Comment: I would ask this on the GitHub issues of the Angular Universal library https://github.com/angular/angular/issues

Comment: Trying to figure it out as well. Not sure if GitHub repo is the place to go as it's an AWS related item.

Comment: I had the same confusion. Please let me know if you get any clarity.